# When trying to deploy to tomcat, Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Dao-hbm.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:/sss.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${driverClass}"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${minPoolSize}"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${maxPoolSize}"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${maxIdleTime}"/>
        <property name="maxStatements" value="${maxStatements}"/>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${idleConnectionTestPeriod}"/>
        <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="${autoCommitOnClose}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${user}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbcUrl}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
            <value>ups/scanning/spss/hibernate/sss.hbm.xml</value>

                       .....    
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hbmDialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hbmShowSql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hbmFormatSql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hbmSqlComments}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <bean id="sssLoadDao" class="ups.scanning.spss.dao.sssLoadHbmDao"/>
    <bean id="sssPieceDao" class="ups.scanning.spss.dao.sssPieceHbmDao"/>   
     .....
</beans>
```

pom dependencies I have,

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>  
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.client-drivers</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java-client-driver</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

tried to match all versions, removed. cleared local repository, still getting the same error. Any suggestions on whats need to be corrected?
Stack strace,

```
 15:32:36,407 ERROR ContextLoader:318 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0
' defined in class path resource [dao-hbm.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; n
ested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invoke
BeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:650)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebA
pplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationConte
xt(ContextLoader.java:293)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitiali
zed(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContex
t.java:4701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:
5204)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:
5199)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL
        at org.springframework.expression.TypedValue.<clinit>(TypedValue.java:32
)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext
.setRootObject(StandardEvaluationContext.java:88)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext
.<init>(StandardEvaluationContext.java:74)
        at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver
.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:124)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluat
eBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:183)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        ... 18 more
```

Comment: It looks to be a Spring auto wiring issue.  Can't tell root cause from what you posted.

Comment: It does not look like there is a problem with your pom.xml; but rather your Spring configuration. Please show this.

Comment: Please show `dao-hbm.xml`

Comment: @orid added dao-hbm file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are mixing Spring versions and you are mixing Spring Security Versions (3.1.3 and 3.1.4), Spring Security 3.1 has a dependency on Spring 3.0 whereas you are trying to use 3.1. Spring WS 2.1 depends on Spring 3.2... So you have a whole mixture going on.

I would suggest upgrading to Spring 3.2.4 (the latest version) and use a properties element to determine the version instead of specifing it for each dependency. Next to that I also suggest using `<dependencyManagement />` tag to force dependencies on a certain version. And finally (or maybe firstly) I suggest the use of the maven-enforcer-plugin with a dependency convergence rule, this will break the build if there are conflicting versions of certain dependencies.

**Enforcer plugin**

```
<build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <DependencyConvergence/>
                            <bannedDependencies>
                                <searchTransitive>true</searchTransitive>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>commons-logging:commons-logging</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-simple</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </bannedDependencies>
                        </rules>
                        <fail>true</fail>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>    
</build>
```

**Use Properties**

```
<properties>
    <spring-framework.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    <spring-ws.version>2.1.3.RELEASE</spring-ws.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security<groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security<groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<!-- Other dependencies go here -->
```

**Use Dependency Management**

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <!-- Spring WS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-ws.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-ws.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

When you use this you can ommit the version number in de `<dependencies />` section.

This xml excludes commons-logging because we don't use that we use SLF4J with the jcl-over-slf4j wrapper jar. If you want to use commons-logging simply remove the exclusions and rule from the enforcer plugin.

Comment: nice, it helped in fixing the issue!