# Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org/springframework/core/convert/TypeDescriptor.NULL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications

I have upgraded spring jars from 3.0.x to 3.2.x version in my web application. Target environment is Websphere Application Server.

I am getting the following error when I try to hit the welcome page of the webapp in the browser.

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0':
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
 org/springframework/core/convert/TypeDescriptor.NULL
```

It looks like some jar/jars in the build path are dependent on spring 3.0.x. I am not sure though. Will be helpful if anyone could out point the same.

I would also like to know how do I exclude dependency of other jars on spring 3.0.x in dispatcher-servlet.xml. Or should I upgrade any jar?

I am also trying to look for the culprit of the problem.

[image: Build Path Screenshot]

Comment: Check the actual l ibraries in your generated war file. I suspect you still have some older spring jars in there. (Check also the content of your EAR). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967376/when-trying-to-deploy-to-tomcat-caused-by-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-null

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. That has pointed me in the right direction. Though not in the build path but Spring 3.0.x jars were still in the WEB-INF/lib folder. Now that when I removed them the ajax calls in my web-app are failing and I can see in the Firebug the ajax call response is error 406. Looks like my web-app is working on spring 3.0.x and not working well with 3.2.x as ajax calls are failing. I am now going to replace Spring 3.2.3 with 3.2.4. Will see what happens.

Comment: I strongly suggest using something like maven, even for a simple app, saves you a lot of headaches finding dependencies and jars on the internet.

Comment: Well, I agree but it's really not in my hands. It's the way it's being developed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to have find solution of my own problem.

I solved my original problem by removing old spring 3.0.x jars which were still there in
`WEB-INF/lib` directory (but not in class path).

Second thing and answer to my second problem is that, In a Spring 3.2.x jar or above environment,  Ajax call with `content-type` `application/json` do not support calls to url with .htm/.html extensions as web-app server throws 406 error. I had to change url extensions to anything else (.json I used for clarity).

Though there could be a different solution as well, but after searching a lot this is what proved to be a quick fix for me. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

try this command on windows (if you are using maven)

> mvn dependency:tree | find "springframework:" | find ":3.0"

or on *ix

> mvn dependency:tree | grep "springframework:" | grep ":3.0"

that should be the culprit.

or manually issue

> mvn dependency:tree > dep.txt

and view/edit dep.txt and search for ":3.0" (this will find other, non-spring, libraries as well.

Comment: Nope. I am not using maven. For now, it's a simple web app and I  export the project as a war package and then simply deploying on the server. I want to get rid of Spring 3.0.x as I am moving to 3.2.x.

Comment: try to take a look at the deployed app. WEB-INF/lib. Not on the eclipse class path. It may be possible that the jar is not in eclipse classpath but was packed into the war.

Comment: I have removed the Spring 3.0.x jars from WEB-INF/lib. But now the Spring 3.2.x is failing ajax calls with json response. Looks like jackson jars are not compatible enough with Spring 3.2.x framework or vice versa.

Comment: works fine for me. maybe we can have a list of all the jars in WEB-INF/lib and the actual output of the ajax call (error message/stack trace?)