# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL while deploying application to Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, mybatis

I migrate project created in Intellij IDEA into maven. Now when I try to deploy the project into Tomcat I receive and error "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL".

This is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.azcomp.payments</groupId>
<artifactId>PaymentGateway</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>

<name>PaymentGateway</name>
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <springVersion>3.2.4.RELEASE</springVersion>
    <cxf.version>2.6.1</cxf.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>xpp3_min</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4c</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.55</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azcomp</groupId>
        <artifactId>apm_util</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azcomp</groupId>
        <artifactId>apm_data</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azcomp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ias2_util</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <warSourceDirectory>web</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is the applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd

 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
 http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

<!--General configuration ###################################################################################### -->
<bean id="uniqueId" class="java.util.UUID" factory-method="randomUUID"/>

<bean id="cacheFlushInfo" class="com.azcomp.paymentgateway.domain.CacheFlushInfo"/>

<!--enable component scanning (beware that this does not enable mapper scanning!) -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.azcomp.paymentgateway.service"/>

<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="config" />

<!-- enable autowire -->
<context:annotation-config/>
<!--############################################################################################################ -->

<!--AOP Configuration ########################################################################################## -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<!-- Aspect -->
<bean id="aopLogger" class="com.azcomp.paymentgateway.aspects.AopLogger" />
<!--############################################################################################################ -->

<!--CXF Configuration ########################################################################################## -->
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>

<bean id="securityInterceptor" class="com.azcomp.paymentgateway.interceptors.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor"/>

<bean class="com.azcomp.paymentgateway.webservice.PaymentGatewayWebServiceImpl" id="paymentGatewayWebService"/>

<jaxws:endpoint id="webService" implementor="#paymentGatewayWebService" address="/WebService">
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="securityInterceptor"/>
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="mtom-enabled" value="true"/>
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:endpoint>
<!--############################################################################################################ -->

<!--Database configuration ##################################################################################### -->
<bean id="transactionManagerAzis" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceAzis"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManagerBscs" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBscs"/>
</bean>

<!-- enable transaction demarcation with annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerAzis"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerBscs"/>

<!-- define the SqlSessionFactory -->
<bean id="sqlSessionFactoryAzis" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceAzis"/>
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.azcomp.paymentgateway.domain"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactoryBscs" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBscs"/>
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.azcomp.paymentgateway.domain"/>
</bean>

<!-- scan for mappers and let them be autowired -->
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.azcomp.paymentgateway.dao"/>
    <property name="annotationClass" value="com.azcomp.paymentgateway.repositories.AzisRepository"/>
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactoryAzis"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.azcomp.paymentgateway.dao"/>
    <property name="annotationClass" value="com.azcomp.paymentgateway.repositories.BscsRepository"/>
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactoryBscs"/>
</bean>

<beans profile="dev">
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourceAzis" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/ApsuserAtAzistst" resource-ref="true" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourceBscs" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/ApsuserAtBscstest" resource-ref="true" />

    <bean id="config" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location" value="file:${catalina.home}/conf/PaymentGateway/applicationConfig-dev.properties"/>
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="test,default">
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourceAzis" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/ApsuserAtAzistst" resource-ref="true" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourceBscs" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/ApsuserAtBscstest" resource-ref="true" />

    <bean id="config" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location" value="file:${catalina.home}/conf/PaymentGateway/applicationConfig-test.properties"/>
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="production">
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourceAzis" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/ApsuserAtAzis" resource-ref="true" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourceBscs" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/ApsuserAtBscs" resource-ref="true" />

    <bean id="config" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location" value="file:${catalina.home}/conf/PaymentGateway/applicationConfig-production.properties"/>
    </bean>
</beans>

<!--############################################################################################################ -->
```

This is the exception:

```
Sep 25, 2014 6:21:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:441)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1553)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:569)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL
    at org.springframework.expression.TypedValue.<clinit>(TypedValue.java:32)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.setRootObject(StandardEvaluationContext.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.<init>(StandardEvaluationContext.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 54 more
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: How are you running your tomcat? Using maven or do you have an standalone instance? I suggest reviewing the classpath of your application, looks like a dependency issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When trying to deploy to tomcat, Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967376/when-trying-to-deploy-to-tomcat-caused-by-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-null)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, the error is produced from the mismatched version of the Spring framework and I notice that you need spring-core, spring-transaction etc in the same project.

So now, i suggest you to make sure the compatibility of the different spring versions.